# Twig nested loop display only the last array

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to display all events belonging to each organizer. If there is duplicate content for the oragnizer's name, it will only display the events belonging to the organizer with the highest id.

**Organizer table**

```
|id   |name        |
--------------------
|1    |organizer 1 |
|2    |organizer 1 |
```

**Event table**

```
|id   |name    |organizer_id  |
-------------------------------
|1    |event 1 |1             |
|2    |event 2 |2             |
```

**Twig**

```
{% for organizer in organizers %}
  {% for event in organizer %}
    {{ event.name }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Result**

```
event2
```

**Result wished**

```
event1
event2
```

Comment: No, the code is correct. Your organizer data may not be. Can you dump what is inside?

Comment: @Tokeeen.com If there is duplicate content organizers contains only one array `array:1 ["organizer 1" => array:1 []]`. Otherwise organizers contains two arrays `array:2 ["organizer 1" => array:1 [] "organizer 2" => array:1 []]`

Comment: The error doesn't come from Twig but before when you get your data. Can you do a dump(organizer) in your controller and add the infos in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve solved the problem by adding a constraint of unicity on organiser name. So the Organizer table, can’t have the same organizer name twice